# Converting AIFF to MP3 in iTunes on El Capitain

Tags: itunes

In my MacBook, running El Capitan 10.11.6 with iTunes 12.4.3.1. I'm right clicking on the sound file inside iTunes in order to convert it from an AIFF to a MP3 — I do not see either of the options “Create MP3 Version” or “Convert Selection to MP3,” even after restarting iTunes.

How can I convert the file?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Hold option key and File > Convert > Convert to MP3? Anything?

Comment: Great, I added it as an answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hold <kbd>option</kbd> while selecting the file(s), and then go to `File > Convert > Convert` to MP3. You should see the option there.